# Using IE to export webpage contents into Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I need to pull school names and abbreviations from [this page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colloquial_names_for_universities_and_colleges_in_the_United_States).

Abbreviations will go in column A and school names in column B.

I am hoping to use [the feature in IE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/getting-data-from-the-web-in-excel-HA001045085.aspx) but I can't seem to figure out if certain aspects of the page can be exported with exporting the entire page.

I can't seem to figure out what settings need to be changed to get this to work.

Comment: Not to be pendantic, but the answer to the only actual question in this post is "Yes". For future questions, please choose an appropriate and concise title and try to frame the main point of the post as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one time thing you should be able to get close to what you need.
On a new worksheet, if you select the one choice available

[image]

and follow the directions importing it to you worksheet to range A1, you will have extraneous rows, but you can copy just A16:A380 to another worksheet.
While the range is selected on that new worksheet, choose DATA>Text to Columns and make the delimiter be "-" (a minus sign) this will give you basically what you need.
From this, sort A:B on A and remove the empty and [edit] heading rows you don't need.

Because the data is not in a separate table you can't automate this easily, but even that could be done with a macro, if this is not a one time effort.

This example is office 2003 but the same idea can be done with the other versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a VBA macro to do this then here's the code you would need. You need to set a reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" then create and run this macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim domResult As DOMDocument60
Dim ixnlLi As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim sResult As String
Dim iDashPos As Integer

Set domResult = New DOMDocument60
domResult.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
domResult.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'"
domResult.resolveExternals = True
domResult.validateOnParse = False
domResult.async = False
domResult.Load "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colloquial_names_for_universities_and_colleges_in_the_United_States"


Set ixnlLi = domResult.selectNodes("id('bodyContent')/ns:ul/ns:li")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents
    For iRow = 1 To ixnlLi.Length
        sResult = ixnlLi(iRow - 1).Text
        iDashPos = InStr(sResult, "-")
        If (iDashPos > 0) Then
            .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Trim$(Left$(sResult, (iDashPos - 1)))
            .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Trim$(Mid$(sResult, (iDashPos + 1)))
        Else
            .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = sResult
            .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = ""
        End If
    Next iRow
    .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

This will be quite a fragile solution though because if someone alters the page structure, the XPath expression used in `selectNodes` would break. You could use a simpler and less fragile expression `//ns:li` in `selectNodes` but this will pull through some other extraneous values from the page which you would have to delete from your list.

That Wikipedia page is not valid XHTML (due to two empty `<ul></ul>` tag pairs)